# Что такое и для чего сделано "var carElement = $(carHtml);"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я новичок в JS и jQuery. Читаю "JavaScript для детей". Дошел до машинок. Имеем код внутри функции.

```
var carHtml = '<img src="car.png">';
var carElement = $(carHtml);
carElement.css({position: "absolute", left: car.x, top: car.y});
$("body").append(carElement);
```

Мне не понятна вторая строка. Чего мы ей достигли?

Comment: создали jQuery объект-обертку вокруг DOM-элемента (пока еще не вставленного в страницу), соответствующего html-у из первой строки

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае `$` является алиасом для функции [`jQuery`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

В указанной строке, этой функции передается строка, выглядящая как html. В этом случае jQuery создает DOM элементы, и возвращает новый jQuery объект, который ссылается на созданные элементы.